# How to pick individual Divs from While loop with JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

Ok, so Iv got a while loop that will display loads and loads of results and iv got it so that there is a button to the side of each result which says "display more".  So when I click display more Iv got some javascript that will "FadeIn()" the rest of the result.
I have done this before when there was only one result on the page, but now iv got loads of results, so how do I identiy just the one that iv clicked.  Here is the JavaScript I currently Have

```
var command = false;
function slideup() { //New function SlidUp
    if (command == false){
         $('#full_result').fadeIn();
         $('#more').text('Display More');
         command = true;
    }else{
         $('#full_result').hide();
         $('#more').text('Display Less');
         command = false;
    }
}
```

So this works fine if there is one result on the page.  But How would I identify each result seperatly.  Here is the code I have to display my results...

```
<table id="browsedata" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="90%" class="quest"><?php echo $row_condition['data']; ?></td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="viewit"><a id="more" href="#" onClick="slideup()">Display More</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="questiondetail">Added by: <?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
        <td class="questiondetail" width="30%">Date Added: <?php echo $dd."/".$mmm."/".$yyyy ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div id="full_result">
                <!-- Full Result will be displayed here -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So that will be repeated for each result, so when I click the "Display More" button, how do I make the JavaScript run just on that result and not the others?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry VisioN, just realised I said JavaScript and not jQuery

Comment: Global variables and IDs are meant to be shared in their whole scope, if you don't like them, forget about IDs and use some `(function(){}){}` to separate scopes.